# map array index to dictionnary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, arraylist

I have an array like this:

```
[[12, 14, 74, 55, 78 ]]
```

And a dictionnary like:

```
{'apple': 0, 'banana': 4, 'ice': 3, 'orange': 2, 'cheese': 1 }
```

The values of the dictionnary keys is the index of the array, I want this result in Python 3:

```
apple=12
banana=78
ice=55
orange=74
cheese=14
```

Comment: That's it? Are you sure you haven't missed your code that' not working and you know where is the problem and you're looking for a workaround :)?

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
first = [[12, 14, 74, 55, 78 ]]

second = {'apple': 0, 'banana': 4, 'ice': 3, 'orange': 2, 'cheese': 1 } 

result = {key: first[0][val] for key, val in second.items()}
# {'apple': 12, 'banana': 78, 'ice': 55, 'orange': 74, 'cheese': 14}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, something like this?

```
>>> l = [[12, 14, 74, 55, 78 ]]
>>> d = {'apple': 0, 'banana': 4, 'ice': 3, 'orange': 2, 'cheese': 1 }
>>> out = {}
>>> for k, v in d.items():
...    out[k] = l[0][v]
...    
>>> out
{'apple': 12, 'banana': 78, 'ice': 55, 'orange': 74, 'cheese': 14}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the dictionary and print all of the keys along with the corresponding value in the array:

```
somedict = {'apple': 0, 'banana': 4, 'ice': 3, 'orange': 2, 'cheese': 1 }
somearray = [12, 14, 74, 55, 78]
for k, v in somedict.items():
    print(k + '=' + str(somearray[v]))
```